# Как починить криво отражающийся текст в QPlainTextEdit в PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread, qtextedit

Немного контекста:

Приложение разбито на классы интерфейса, управления и внутренней логики. Они соединены с помощью паттерна "наблюдатель". Логика запускается в отдельном потоке через QThreadPool в классе управления. Периодически класс логики посылает сообщения интерфейсу, которые отображаются в QLineEdit и QPlainTextEdit, совсем не так, как надо. Так же, параллельно запущен поток, в котором происходит отслеживание нажатия сочетания клавиш. Если изменить размер интерфейса (потянув за край) - текст приходит в норму.

Подозреваю, что проблема может быть в работе потоков, но не могу понять, в чём именно.
Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Реализация "наблюдателя":

```
class Observer(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def event_happened(self, text: str) -> None:
        pass

class Observable(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self._list_observers: List[Observer] = []

    def copy_list(self, list_observers: List[Observer]):
        self._list_observers = list_observers

    def get_list(self):
        return self._list_observers

    def attach(self, observer: Observer) -> None:
        self._list_observers.append(observer)

    def detach(self, observer: Observer) -> None:
        if observer in self._list_observers:
            self._list_observers.remove(observer)

    def notify_event_happened(self, text: str) -> None:
        for observer in self._list_observers:
            observer.event_happened(text)
```

В дальнейшем Observer наследуется и метод event_happened определяется в каждом конкретном классе.

Ввод текст в QPlainTextEdit:

```
class View(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, view.Ui_MainWindow, Observer, metaclass=Meta):
    ...
    def update_log(self, event: str) -> None:
        self.text_log.appendPlainText(event)
        self.text_log.update()
```

Запуск логики и отслеживания нажатия сочетания в отдельных потоках:

```
class Controller:
    def __init__(self, model: Model):
        ...
        self._threadpoll = PyQt5.QtCore.QThreadPool()

    def start_request(self) -> None:
        self.update_model()
        self._threadpoll.start(self._model.start)
        self._threadpoll.start(self._model.wait_signal_about_escape)
```

[image: Кривой текст в QLineEdit и QPlainTextEdit]

Comment: Каким образом можно связать работу потоков и изменение размера интерфейса ? Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: `соединены с помощью паттерна "наблюдатель"` как именно это реализовано? Через `сигнал/слот` Qt или самописный механизм?

Comment: @S.Nick я не связывал это, скорее заметил как факт, что когда текст вводится из класса интерфейса - всё нормально. Но при передаче текста из другого класса, находящегося в другом потоке - происходит то, что видно на скриншоте, плюс иногда идёт просто какое-то наслоение текста друг на друга. А из-за того, что текст приходит в норму при изменения размера интерфейса, у меня возникло ощущение, что интерфейс не обновляется, однако даже вызов метода update интерфейса или конкретного элемента не помогло.
Минимальный воспроизводимый пример постараюсь сгенерировать чуть дальше

Comment: @MaximTimakov Самописный. Через два класса: Observer и Observable. Observable содержит список подключённых к нему Observer, которые он может "обзванивать", сами классы в последствии наследуются другими.

Comment: Если реализовано [как то так](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#Python), то получится что методы GUI вызываются в другом потоке, что недопустимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С виджетами нельзя работать на прямую из потоков, отличных от потока UI.
Для обхода этого ограничения нужно использовать очереди событий.

Попробуйте так:

```py
class View(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, view.Ui_MainWindow, Observer, metaclass=Meta):
    update_log = Signal(str)
    
    def _init__(self, ...):
        # ....
        self.update_log.connect(self.do_update_log)
    #...
    
    def event_happened(self, text: str) -> None:
        self.update_log.emit(text)
    
    @Slot(str)
    def do_update_log(self, event: str) -> None:
        self.text_log.appendPlainText(event)
        self.text_log.update()
```

"Синтаксис" сигналов/слотов из `PySide2`: для `PyQt5` нужно будет объявить псевдонимы:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import \
    pyqtSlot as Slot, pyqtSignal as Signal
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло =)